# Exe file not executing custom code to output a number to command prompt (Windows)

Tags: assembly, exe, portable-executable

I made a custom .exe file from scratch. The problem is it won't execute or basically run my code.

Custom Code in the .text section of exe(in raw Hex code) is,

```
{ 0xB2, 0x41, 0xB4, 0x06, 0xCD, 0x15, 0xC3 }
```

Assembly Version,

```
mov    dl,0x41
mov    ah,0x6
int    0x15
ret
```

I tried `ah,02` also but it didn't work.(ref:http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html)

I tried running from command prompt also but nothing happens. After I hit enter it just shows my current path.

My Question,

Is my assembly Code or hex code right?If not what is the opcodes which I have to use(for Intel) to just output a number or character when I run my exe?

Comment: int 0x15 is a DOS interrupt, not a Windows interrupt. You can't use it inside a PE file without it most likely faulting on you.

Comment: @Michaek Petch Okay, then do you know what are the opcodes for windows interrupt? Basically, to output a character or number in windows console or standard output console?

Comment: You need to use the Windows API. Exactly like you would in C. Eventually, write the program in C first.

Comment: @Margaret Bloom Is this set of functions a good place to start? [link(]https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx) Let me know if you have any other links that might help me.